# Automation of generating pstricks graphics with texclipse before pdf generation

Tags: pdf, pstricks, automation, texlipse

When using eclipse with pdflatex I want it to create the pstricks Images automatically. The classical way (without eclipse or texlipse) would be:

```
latex test.tex
dvips -o test-pics.ps test.dvi
ps2pdf test-pics.ps
```

and then one would use pdflatex. How can I make texlipse do this automatically for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you can run `pdflatex -shell-escape <file>` with package `auto-pst-pdf`
- or run `pst2pdf <file>` to create all images on the fly as png or pdf or ...
- you can run `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex` without any additional package or additional conversion

Comment: Thanks. auto-pst-pdf works for me. This solution makes however some problems, when you have png graphics included in the same document.

Comment: @Igor: You cannot use `auto-pst-pdf` to draw or overlay PSTricks objects on the existing EPS images.

Comment: @Igor: it should be no problem to insert png or pdf images into your document which uses package `auto-pst-pdf`

Comment: @xport: why should this it not be possible to draw over an eps?

Comment: @Herbert: It is a typo. I meant PNG, JPEG or PDF rather than EPS.